# git: aborting pull because of Gemfile.lock file which would be overwritten, even though it is in the .gitignore file

Tags: git

I'm pulling my project with git.

I get this error: `error: Your local changes to 'Gemfile.lock' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.`.

But 'Gemfile.lock' is in my .gitignore file, so git should not be interested in overwriting this file.

Any help?

Greets, Joern.

Comment: Git does not ignore files which are already in the repository. No idea what to do here, though.

Answer (score 0):

When a file is ignored by git, it is just excluded when you do a recursive `git add`. But `git` will never overwrite a file in a repository if it is not tracked (principe of least surprise). The ignored file could be expensive (time, ...) to generate.

However, even if a file is ignored someone can have committed a file with the same name (either with `git add -f` or because they have changed the .gitignore file in the same commit).

So if the file has been incorrectly added in a commit, you can rewrite history to remove it (if the repository has not been shared), you can create a new commit that remove the file in the other branch, and then merge it, or you can move away your local file, merge, and restore your local file.

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting the file, then pulling and then making a bundle install again.

Answer (score 0):

Gemfile.lock must have been parth to the repository, otherwise git would not complain about it.